# Create a new column for a dataframe based on a complicated dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-manipulation

I have a complicated dictionary to remap values. How do I achieve this in python?

```
cols_to_check = ["ColA","ColB","ColC"]
dic_string = "{(Type 1 | Type 2) : Type dual,
       (Type 3 | Type 4) : Type many,
        ELSE: Not listed
       }"
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
        'ID': ['AB01', 'AB02', 'AB03', 'AB04', 'AB05','AB06','AB07','AB08'],
        'ColA': ["Type 1","Undef",np.nan,"Undef",
                 "Type 1", "","", "Undef"],
        'ColB': ["N","Type 2","","",
                 "Y", np.nan,"", "N"],
        'ColC': [np.nan,"Undef","Type 3",np.nan,"Undef",
                 "Undef", "","Type 2"]
})
```

I can do if it's a simple dictionary and if there is no ELSE mentioned in it. Assuming I can convert the 'dic_string' to following:

```
dic = {"Type 1" : "Type dual","Type 2" : "Type dual",
   "Type 3" : "Type many", "Type 4" : "Type many",
    "ELSE": "Not listed"
   }
```

How can I make the end result like this with the new column "Result". How do I achieve this without hardcoding the contents of dic?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
dic = {('Type 1', 'Type 2'): 'Type dual',
       ('Type 3', 'Type 4'): 'Type many',}
default = 'Not listed'

condlist = [df[cols_to_check].isin(k).any(axis=1) for k in dic]
choicelist = dic.values()

df['Result'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default)
```

Output:

```
     ID    ColA    ColB    ColC      Result
0  AB01  Type 1       N     NaN   Type dual
1  AB02   Undef  Type 2   Undef   Type dual
2  AB03     NaN          Type 3   Type many
3  AB04   Undef             NaN  Not listed
4  AB05  Type 1       Y   Undef   Type dual
5  AB06             NaN   Undef  Not listed
6  AB07                          Not listed
7  AB08   Undef       N  Type 2   Type dual
```

Comment: Is there a way I can use 'dic' instead hardcoding the stuff in it?

Comment: Your dictionary is not a valid python `dict`

Comment: What if I converted the dic to `dic = {"Type 1" : "Type dual","Type 2" : "Type dual",
                                                      "Type 3" : "Type many", "Type 4" : "Type many",
                                                      "ELSE": "Not listed"
                                                        }`

Comment: Can you check my updated answer, please?

Comment: I've checked, I'll try to get the dic to the above format like you've used.